# Magento local install MAMP Pro 4

Tags: magento-1.9, localhost, mamp

Mage: 1.9.2
mysql: 5.6.28
php: 5.6.25

I have local copy of magento 1.9.2 in FAP dir, have database imported and connected via etc/local.xml

In mamp pro-4: added host FAP & pointed directory to FAP dir (magento root).
in core_config_data I have http://fap/ in secure/base_url as well as unsecure/base_url.

When I open host in browser it loads http://fap:8888 however js or css are not loading and when I add /admin to a url I get:

> Not Found The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.

I'm guessing problem is in core_config_data settings, but I've tried pretty much everything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason .htaccess file in magento root directory didnt get zipped during the installation transfer.

After adding an original .htaccess file all works well.